# cross domain issue in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I am new to the cross domain issue, i had developed one UI application, from that i call the web services via Ajax call If I run that application as localhost it works perfectly for **ex(http://localhost:8080/CNext/)**. If i run that application by using my local IP **(http://192.168.1.71:8080/CNext)** except **'GET'** method i got the following error 
**'Access is Denied JQuery.min.js'**. My service is run on some other machine. what should i do for resolve that issue. My JQuery Ajax  code is as follows.How to resolve this **cross domain issue**

```
            $.ajax({
                url: securityGroupURL,
                data: JSON.stringify(testData),                    
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {                        
                    alert(data.SecurityGroupId);                            
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error :"+errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/ajax-cross-domain-142169

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the domain in your AJAX request matches the domain of the page and your javascript file.